# Change color of a hotspot region on mousehover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, imagemap

I am generating HotSpot on Image Map control dynamically. Here is the code

```
// Programmatically create a RectangleHotSpot.
RectangleHotSpot Rectangle1 = new RectangleHotSpot();
Rectangle1.Top = 50;
Rectangle1.Left = 10;
Rectangle1.Bottom = 200;
Rectangle1.Right = 200;
Rectangle1.NavigateUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";

ImageMap1.HotSpots.Add(Rectangle1);
```

This is done on PageLoad, now i want to Set color of the hotspot on mousehover i.e once user takes his mouse over the hotspot region the colour shold change and should be somewhat transperant. how can this be done?

Comment: use Javascript MouseHover Property

Comment: Dont know asp.net but i guess you could do it with css on the output of the html thats get generated troughout your .net

Comment: If you want to do using CSS on HTML side, can show you an example

Answer (score 0):

Dont know asp.net but i guess you could do it with css on the output of the html thats get generated troughout your .net

Like if you have the output

```
<div id="hotspot"></div>
```

css:

```
#hotspot{
background:red;
width:20px;
Height:20px;
}
#hotspot:hover{
background:blue;
}
```

This exact same can be done with background pictures

css like this:

```
#hotspot{
background:url('your img url')no-repeat;
width:20px;
Height:20px;
}
#hotspot:hover{
background:url('your hover img url')no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend this plugin enough for this.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

It will do exactly what you want and the author is genuinely helpful if you can't work it out.